# Magento Backend Doesn't Work

Tags: magento-1.9

When i log in magento backend, it looks like attached:[image]

Any suggestion to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Please view the source code of the page (Ctrl+U). Then search for **.css** and copy the full URL of the CSS file and open it in separate tab in your browser and check what is happening.

Another thing that you can try is to delete all files from directories **media/js**, **media/css**, **media/css_secure**.

Comment: Well, at first i dont think its about css but i tried something you mentioned and it didnt work. But i find out something like, the admin url was http://domain.com/index.php/admin when i open this link, even the login page didnt work. but when i open http://domain.com/admin  the login page works. but after i login from the second url, it redirects to index.php again and the backend goes down. I find out this detail but i still dont know what to do.. @michael

Comment: Try to replace your .htaccess file with such from clean Magento installation/archive.